# For loop with if statement

Tags: r

I'm a MATLAB user and only just new to R, I've created a for loop with an if statement included.  The variable "score10" is a set of random numbers between 0 to 10. group is the empty set group <- c().  Essentially i want to dicotamise the scores.  When I run the code below the variable group gives me a 1 then a series of NA and a 0 at the 1279th entry.  Where am I going wrong?  Thanks in advance

```
group <- c()
for(i in 1:1279) {
    if (score10[i] <= 4) {
        group[i] = 0
    } else {
        group[i] = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: To answer your question, whenever `if(score10[i] <= 4)` condition is false, it does `group = 1` which overwrites `group` as a single valued vector with value `1`. I'm guessing that the last value of `score10` is `<= 4` but the second-last one isn't which means that at the 1278th iteration of the loop, `group` is just a single value of `1` and in particular has no entry in the first 1278 components of the vector. When the if condition is true, R does it's best and creates an empty vector in the first 1278 entries and assigns the 1279th one with `1`.

Comment: So you could change the second last line of your code to `} else group[i] = 1` to achieve what you want. However, this isn't idiomatic R programming and will be slow for larger problems.

Comment: I am a goose, thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on Ananda Mahto's answer, you can also use `ifelse` for this.

```
> score <-sample(10, 20, TRUE)
> score
## [1] 10  4  6  3  9  8  1  5  1 10  9  5  2  6 10  2  7 10  5  9
> ifelse(score <= 4, 0, 1)
## [1] 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: +1 I just posted that in my update, but I'll delete it.

Comment: Any time.  @AnandaMahto put up some benchmarks illustrating how fast these processes are. The `for` loop in R is actually almost always one of the the slowest.

Comment: Richard, see my update. @user3547580, I've updated my answer to show how to "fix" your `for` loop, but that also shows why your approach is definitely not the one to take when using R.

Comment: So lets say now, i wanted to break it up into 3 groups, i.e. between 0 and 3, 4-5, and 6-10. giveing the values of 1,2,3 respectivly if I wanted to tricotomise my data.  How would I go about this?

Comment: @user3547580, that's a different question, but try `cut` or `findInterval`.

Comment: just for future reference, I didnt know but you can stack ifelse commands, i just used that to split the data into 3

Answer (score 1):

There are much better ways to do this in R. Just use a logical comparison and convert it to `numeric`:

```
set.seed(1)
score10 <- sample(10, 20, TRUE)
score10
# [1]  3  4  6 10  3  9 10  7  7  1  3  2  7  4  8  5  8 10  4  8
score10 > 4
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [13]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
as.numeric(score10 > 4)
# [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1
```

---

If you wanted to go with your `for` loop approach, try this instead:

```
group <- integer(length(score10)) ## Initializes a vector of zeroes
group
#  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
for (i in seq_along(score10)) {
  if (score10[i] > 4) group[i] <- 1L
}
group
# [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1
```

---

To justify my statement about "there are much better ways to do this in R", here are some benchmarks:

```
set.seed(1)
score10 <- sample(10, 1e5, TRUE)
fun1 <- function() as.numeric(score10 > 4)
fun2 <- function() ifelse(score10 <= 4, 0, 1)
fun3 <- function() {
  group <- integer(length(score10))
  for (i in seq_along(score10)) {
    if (score10[i] > 4) group[i] <- 1L
  }
  group 
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2(), fun3(), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min         lq     median         uq        max neval
#  fun1()   1.58363   1.597111   1.629187   1.645506   3.259797    10
#  fun2()  46.28590  46.358392  47.935876  48.309711  48.402714    10
#  fun3() 146.12897 149.051372 149.285990 150.827876 153.211941    10
```

---

#### Final update

"Fixing" your `for` loop will also show you why your current approach, which grows a vector instead of preallocating it, is a *really* bad idea.

```
fun3b <- function() {
  group <- c()
  for (i in seq_along(score10)) {
    if (score10[i] > 4) {
      group[i] <- 1L
    } else {
      group[i] <- 0L
    }
  }
  group 
}
```

Or, more concisely, but just as slow:

```
fun3c <- function() {
  group <- c()
  for (i in seq_along(score10)) {
    group[i] <- if (score10[i] > 4) 1L else 0L
  }
  group 
} 

## The "fix"
system.time(fun3b())
#    user  system elapsed 
#  10.171   0.010  10.212 

## The modified version I mentioned earlier
system.time(fun3())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.151   0.000   0.155 

## The R way to do things
system.time(fun1())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.001   0.000   0.001
```